# Looking up fixed key value pairs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code some functions to look up area codes based on the specified city. 
Two questions...
1) Why is my else statement not working?
2) How do I retrieve the value of the key that matches the user input?

```js
let areaCodes = {
  'San Francisco': 102,
  'Portland': 200,
  'Boston': 10
}

// prompt user for input and return output

function userPrompt(list) {
  var ans = prompt('Would you like to look up a city by area code? (Y/N)');

  if (ans = 'Y') {
    return Object.keys(list);
  } else {
    return 'What would you like to do?';
  }
}


// analyse input

function inputAnalysis(list) {
  var input = prompt('Which city would you like to look up?');

  if (list.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
    console.log('The area code for ' + input + ' is: ' + list.valueOf(input))
  }
}
```

Comment: typo `if (ans == 'Y') {`instead of `if (ans = 'Y') {`  .invalid if condition

Comment: You are using an assignment operator `=`. You should use `===`

Comment: If list equals areaCodes, `list[ input ]` will give you the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is correct, just you need to remove one error from your **userPrompt function**.

```
function userPrompt (list) {
    var ans = prompt('Would you like to look up a city by area code? (Y/N)');

    if (ans == 'Y') { // <--- Make it "==" to work.
        return Object.keys(list);
    }
    else 
    {
        return 'What would you like to do?'; 
    }
}
```

and

```
function inputAnalysis(list) {
  var input = prompt('Which city would you like to look up?');

  if (list.hasOwnProperty(input)) {
    console.log('The area code for ' + input + ' is: ' + list[input]) // <--- to avoid [object object] error.
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but do you really need the else block, you could just return (as it would anyhow return when ans is Y (so you can make it `if (ans === 'Y') { return Object.keys(list); } return 'What would you like to do';`

Comment: thank you :-)
a quick question... why does list[input] retrieve the value? I thought list[input] would end up retrieving the key.